# Multi Variable datasets

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, variable

I've a dataset that contains several attributes and a KPI column. I would like to understand through statistics which of the attributes are more important or key attributes in influencing this KPI column. Is there a statistic model that I could run to get this analysis?

Please help, As you can imagine, I'm a novice in this field.

Thanks.